# Set JVM option for forked tests in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two sets of tests, one that needs to be run with the JVM `-javaagent` set, and one that needs it unset. I am using `Groups` to run on separate JVMs, and I can see both java processes start. Using `jps -lvm` I can see no JVMs are running with the `-javaagent` flag.

`build.sbt`:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    resolvers           ++= Build.resolvers,
    libraryDependencies ++= Build.dependencies,

    fork in Test := true,
    testGrouping := groupByJavaAgent((definedTests in Test).value),
    tags in test += Tags.ForkedTestGroup -> 4
  )

val home = System.getProperty("user.home")

val jammForkOpts = ForkOptions()
  .withRunJVMOptions(Vector(s"-javaagent:$home/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jbellis/jamm/jars/jamm-0.3.3.jar"))

def groupByJavaAgent(allTests: Seq[TestDefinition]) = allTests
  .groupBy(t => if(t.name.contains("no javaagent")) ("NoJamm", ForkOptions())
                else                                ("Jamm",   jammForkOpts))
  .map { case ((gName, opts), tests) => Group(gName, tests, SubProcess(opts)) }
  .toSeq
```

`sbt 1.2.8` `scala 2.12.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try scoping `testGrouping` by `Test` configuration like so

```
Test / testGrouping := groupByJavaAgent((definedTests in Test).value)
```

which on my machine gives

```
➜  ~ jps -lvm
54513 sbt.ForkMain 52222 -javaagent:/Users/mario_galic/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jbellis/jamm/jars/jamm-0.3.3.jar
54514 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home -Xms8m
54331 /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.2.8/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```